# How to write a python program that takes a number from the users and prints the divisors of that number and then print how many divisors were there?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code so far

```
n=int(input('Enter the value of n: '))
for i in range(n):
    if(n%i==0):
        print(i, end=',')
```

I don't know how to find the number of divisors so i do the first part of the question. Please help me to find it.

Comment: What's wrong with your code so far? It is indeed printing the numbers that divide n evenly. If you need to know how many divisors there are total, just declare a variable outside of the for loop and increment it within the if condition.

Comment: Create a counter with count `0`, every time your code finds a divisor, add one to the counter.

Comment: "how many divisors" is same as "how many times you print divisors". Why not have a counter that increments everytime you print?

Answer (score 2):

You could define a list variable and append to this one if the condition is met:

```
n = int(input('Enter the value of n: '))
divisors = []
for i in range(1, n):
    if n % i == 0:
        divisors.append(i)

print(divisors)
print(len(divisors))
```

Now, `len(divisors)` is the number of divisors.

---

E.g. with an input of `100`, the script yields

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50]
8
```

Get accustomed to list comprehensions in `Python`:

```
divisors = [i for i in range(1, n) if not n % i]
```

Answer (score 2):

#I have solved it using string as I was asked to show a output added with comma

```
num = int(input('Enter the value of num: '))
div = ""
count=0
for j in range(1, num+1):
       if num % j == 0:
            count+=1
            if  j!=num:
                div+=str(j)+", "
            else:
                div+=str(j)

print(div)
print("Total", count, "divisors")
```

Comment: Seeing as Jan correctly answered the question just before I posted mine how can I delete my comment?

Comment: No worries, the answer stays correct, doesn't it? +1

Comment: Right you are. Happy to contribute.